# Use of validator in collection defined in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, validation, data-modeling

Basically, I am new to MongoDB and learning from documents. I wanted to use validator, validationLevel, validationAction while defining a collection in MongoDB. So I can get an error if validated data is not inserted or updated. I have followed [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/) document for reference. However, I got success in defining collection but when I add the wrong record it doesn't give me error like it is mentioned in documents. Everytime new record is getting inserted. Can you guys please help me in this whats wrong with my code.

I am using the following command to create a collection

```
db.createCollection( "contacts",
{
      validator: { $and:
         [
            { phone: { $type: "string" } },
            { email: { $regex: /@mongodb\.com$/ } },
            { status: { $in: [ "Unknown", "Incomplete" ] } }
         ],
       validationAction: "error"
      }
   }
)
```

I have also used the same command with validationLevel to strict like below but it also didn't work out.

```
db.createCollection( "contacts",
{
      validator: { $and:
         [
            { phone: { $type: "string" } },
            { email: { $regex: /@mongodb\.com$/ } },
            { status: { $in: [ "Unknown", "Incomplete" ] } }
         ],
       validationAction: "error",
       validationLevel: "strict"
      }
   }
)
```

A command I used to insert record is as below

```
db.contacts.insert( { name: "Amanda", status: "Updated" } )
```

Below is the expected output as per the document.

```
WriteResult({
   "nInserted" : 0,
   "writeError" : {
      "code" : 121,
      "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
   }
})
```

But I end up getting success output as below

```
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you validation rule is not applied to the collection. You can check for the same using 
`getCollectionInfos({name:'constacts'})` 
here is the [link](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionInfos/).

Comment: Yes it is not being applied but when we run command to apply validation it gives success. So what can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Error is in the `validationAction` and `validationLevel`.

use this

```
db.createCollection( "contacts", { validator: 
  { $and: 
      [ 
          { phone: { $type: "string" } }, 
          { email: { $regex: /@mongodb\.com$/ } }, 
          { status: { $in: [ "Unknown", "Incomplete" ] } }
      ]
   },
   validationLevel : "strict",
   validationAction : "error"
  } 
)
```

insted of

```
db.createCollection( "contacts",
{
  validator: { $and:
     [
        { phone: { $type: "string" } },
        { email: { $regex: /@mongodb\.com$/ } },
        { status: { $in: [ "Unknown", "Incomplete" ] } }
     ],
   validationAction: "error",
   validationLevel: "strict"
   }
 }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Quote from documentation:

> You cannot specify a validator for collections in the admin, local,
>   and config databases. You cannot specify a validator for system.*
>   collections.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.createCollection/